# Adjusting highlights, shadows, etc in LR

Tags: lightroom, image-processing

There are two areas in LR when you develop your image where you can adjust these parameters, one in the curves section and one overall I think. What's the difference and when should you use which?

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/61211/15871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main area sliders have preset brightness points they act on, they are the 'quick and easy' solution.

The curves section gives a lot more control, as you can position not only the sliders, but also their attack points (in the diagram, click the little triangles at the bottom and drag them left/right).

If you move them exactly to the predefined settings of the main area sliders, there is no difference in their activities.